# Regex for anything but multicharacter token

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation

I want to create a regex that returns everything between two multicharacter tokens where the opening token is `;;(` and the closing token is `;;)`, such as

```
;;(
  Capture this part, which can contain everything except the closing token 
;;)
```

I thought the regex `/;;\((?!;;\));;\)/` using negative lookahead should work but this is returning no matches. Is it possible to use a regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind and positive lookahead.

```
(?<=;;\().*?(?=;;\))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/iK5wG4/2

Comment: I would not recommend any lookaheads here. Just capture what you need, match the delimiters but do not capture them. Use `/;;\((.*?);;\)/` and get the value with index 1. Lookarounds involve additional overhead. They are not supported by all languages, either.

Comment: @stribizhev I like the lookahead/behind because this approach will not break when you want to find multiple such groups in a longer string.

Comment: You can do the same with my version of the regex. Even more efficiently, quicker. I would not use lazy dot matching, I'd use an unrolled one. Yours takes **169** steps. I'd use [`;;\(([^;]*(?:;(?!;\))[^;]*)*);;\)`](https://regex101.com/r/aC1sU1/1) that takes **16** steps. I guess I need to post that.

Comment: @stribizhev you are right, it works here because the tokens cannot overlap, therefore you won't have a problem with a start/ending token being consumed. Good observation!

Answer (score 2):

In order to match some text between two multicharacter delimiters is a regex that is in line with the **unroll-the-loop** technique.

So, we have `;;(` and `;;)` delimiters.

The lazy dot matching regex is [`;;\((.*?);;\)`](https://regex101.com/r/aC1sU1/2). This pattern is not efficient since it will become slower and slower when larger and larger text comes in as input.

Unrolling it like [`;;\(([^;]*(?:;(?!;\))[^;]*)*);;\)`](https://regex101.com/r/aC1sU1/1) makes matching linear and the only problem can occur with speed if there are many `;` inside the block.

It takes timgeb's solution **169** steps to complete the match. It takes mine just **16** steps.

Also, the unrolled regex does not depend on the `/s` DOTALL modifier, it can be omitted.

**Why not use lookarounds?** Lookarounds are good when you need *overlapping* matches or there are specific conditions. In this case, you need *non-overlapping matches* because the *leading and trailing delimiters are not equal*. **Use capturing groups**, pairs of unescaped parentheses around those subpatterns you need to get. In `;;\(([^;]*(?:;(?!;\))[^;]*)*);;\)`, we need to get all text that is not `;;)`, i.e. this `[^;]*(?:;(?!;\))[^;]*)*` part. Thus, we enclose it with `()`.

**What does this unrolled part match?**

- `[^;]*` - anything but the `;` (the first char of the trailing delimiter)
- `(?:;(?!;\))[^;]*)*` - zero or more sequences of...

  - `;(?!;\))` - the first char of the trailing delimiter, a literal `;` that is not followed by `;)` (the rest of the trailing delimiter)
  - `[^;]*` - zero or more characters other than `;` (the first char of the trailing delimiter)